# Hide Checkbox Icon for a ListItem in checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, styling, checkboxlist, listitem

Is there a way to hide the checkbox icon for an ListItem and just display the value-text.

Like Below - Checkbox for items is hidden.

I could figure out that I could disable (grey-out) or completely hide (invisible) a list item but not just hide the checkbox icon (square)

[image: items is a list item with the checkbox hidden]

Comment: You could use other controls like [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I recently did this as part of a project and accomplished it via setting an attribute when creating the ListItem and then using CSS to style it.

```
li.Attributes.Add("id", "removecheckbox");
```

Since the attribute is added as part of a  tag, you can use the following descriptor in your CSS.

```
#removecheckbox
{
    color: Gray;
}
#removecheckbox input
{
    display: none;
}
```

Of course, you can format the CSS any way you'd like, but this should get you started.
If you'd like more information using selectors in CSS, check out [this reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) from [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/).

HTH!

Comment: Yes, that works well. Referencing the checkbox itself as "input" seems key to both solutions.  I didn't use the Gray part, not required for what I am doing. Thanks :)

Comment: Although when auto-refreshed when another control is selected, the check boxes return :(

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 will help you, define Inline style, good point is to make special UserControl for CheckBoxList to use following solution

```
<style>
    input:disabled {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

and in CheckBoxList PreRender event disable ListItem to apply CSS input:disabled selector

```
protected void CheckBoxListMajad_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem it in this.CheckBoxListMajad.Items)
    {
        if (it.Value.Equals("0"))
        {
            it.Enabled = false;
            it.Selected = false;
            it.Attributes.Add("style", "font-size:14px;height:16px;font-weight:bold;");
        }
    }
}
```

[CheckBoxListMajad.RepeatColumn=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPmtG.png)